# vdirsyncer help needed with config

Tags: configuration, calendar

Trying to setup `vdirsyncer`, this as far as I've got!

When running, I get an error.

```
$ vdirsyncer discover
Section "general", option "status_path": Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Here is my config file:

```
[general]
status_path = “~/.vdirsyncer/status/”

[pair khal_sync]
a = "bill_calendar_local"
b = "bill_calendar_remote"
collections = ["from a", "from b"]

[storage bill_calendar_local]
type = "filesystem"
path = "~/.calendars/"
fileext = ".ics"

[storage bill_calendar_remote]
type = "caldav"
url = "https://caldav.one.com/calendars/users/email/calendar/"
#username =
#password =
```

Comment: Try replacing all the `~/` with the path of your home directory.

Comment: You seem to have Unicode pretty quotes `“”` there instead of normal double quotes `""` in `status_path`.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, just copied the line from the default config and it all worked.